# unexpected string constant in R matrice function

Tags: r

Brand new to `R` and doing battle with the learning curve; Im trying to make a simple table but don't understand the error code I get. Any help much appreciated.

What I type:

```
artists <- matrix(c("RHCP","Foos","Audioslave""Einaudi","Podcasts","Oasis") nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Error:

> unexpected string constant in "artists <-
>   matrix(c("RHCP","Foos","Audioslave""Einaudi""

What is a string constant? Google is not helpful

Answer (score 2):

You just need some commas. Try this:

```
artists <- matrix(c("RHCP", "Foos", "Audioslave", "Einaudi", "Podcasts", "Oasis"),
                  nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: You're welcome! It is [advised](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) to place one "space" after a comma to make R code easier to read and easily find mistakes. Try to keep this practice.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip, I will work on improving my style!